# Whats the maximum throughput per instance can be achieved in IBM MQ Advanced for Developers?

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq

I am currently using a IBM MQ Advanced for Developers server for testing our client and was able to achieve around 1000 messages per second using the sample consumer written in jms, which seems to be pretty slow. Is this a limit for dev server, and if yes that what throughput can be achieved using a licensed production IBM MQ server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no artificial limit associated with IBM MQ Advanced for Developers. It is the same as the licensed production version of IBM MQ.

You don't say what type of machine you were using, what persistence your messages were, what size they were, or any other qualifying criteria.

You say client, but I don't know whether you mean "network attached application" or "driving application". Clearly if your program is running "client-attached" (MQ parlance for network attached), then the network performance will also come into this.

On my Windows laptop, I get 4500 non-persistent msgs/sec, or 2000 persistent msgs/sec using a simple C-language locally bound program. Over client connection (just using localhost, not actually going out over a real network connection) I get 2700 non-persistent msgs/sec, or 1500 persistent msgs/sec.

You should read the [MQ Performance Reports](http://ibm-messaging.github.io/mqperf/) for details of the expected rates you can get.

Answer (score 1):

As an ex MQ performance person I would say - it depends.

At one level you can ask - what can one application in isolation process.
For persistent messages this will come down to the rate at which you can write to the log files.

If you have 10 applications in parallel each putting and getting from their own queue, then you will not get 10 times the throughput - you might get 8 or 9 times the throughput.
If they are all processing the same queue, then the throughput may drop a bit more as the queue usage is serialised.

If only one application is writing to the log, the application may see 1 millisecond response time.  If you have 10 applications running concurrently, they may see a 3 milliseconds response time - so individual throughput goes down, but with more threads, the overall throughput goes up.

If you have requests coming in over the network, you need to add network time, but you can run more clients and so get improved throughput.

If your application has a delay built in - it may only process a low message rate.  You can have lots (1000s) of these and get a high >overall< throughput.
If your application is putting and getting as fast as possible, you may find that you can run 10-100 instances before the throughput plateaus.

Let's say you want to run you box so it is using 75% of the CPU, and the logging is 50% busy.

If you have just MQ on the box, then this can run more messages than if you had DB2 on the box (with DB2 using 50% of the CPU)

If you have an application (DB2) hammering the disk, then the MQ throughput will go down.

If you have lots of applications putting to a server queue - and one server program, you will find the throughput is limited by the rate at which the server can process work.  If it is doing DB2 work, it will be slower than no DB2 work.  If you find the server queue depth is over 5 then you need more server instances.

As Morag said, see the performance reports, but they are not the clearest reports to understand.

Comment: But it is the same between both products, right Colin?

Comment: Yes - same concepts - the implementation is different